# How to download emails from gmail in HIPAA compliant manner?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have a gmail workspace account I want to download emails from, and load them into a database. The emails contain PHI (personal health information) so they must be encrypted at all times up to compliant standards. As far as I can tell, IMAP with TLS 1.2+ enabled is HIPAA compliant. However, I run into some issues when I try to set this up.

1. straight requests using imaplib get the following error:

   ````
   (Pdb) imap_server.login('*****', '****')
   imaplib.IMAP4.error: b'[ALERT] Application-specific password required: 
   https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 (Failure)'```
   ````
2. I cannot make an application password, but instead must use the gmail api. If I want to connect using IMAP, then I need to grant domain wide authority to a service account, which is too great an authority for what is needed, as it can access all the emails in the organization.
3. Another option is to directly issue oauth keys on the account, instead of creating a service account. This works in a practical sense, but then I am not sure that the APIs I am interacting with are HIPAA compliant.

So my question is, how do I download emails from a google workspace account in a HIPAA compliant manner? Is IMAP with a service account my only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can use application passwords...the option is just not easily visible.

https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords is the current location to turn them on, even with organization accounts. So the answer is that IMAP with TLS 1.2+ and an application password is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth to authenticate and authorize the download of the emails in your inbox. This option will create a [consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent) in the browser to authorize the download of the email using the email and password of your workspace account.

[image: sign-in]
[image: consent screen]

You do this by [creating a GCP project](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project), [enable the Google Workspace Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/enable-apis), setup your [configure the OAuth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent), create and download your [OAuth client ID](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id), Lastly, you can add the `authorization flow` in your code. This flow will change depending on the programming language you choose.

E.g for python is:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    
    creds = None
 
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

You can see other examples in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides).

[image: guides]

Or following the steps of the 3rd party application that will help you download the emails for you. If you use Google OAuth it should be HIPAA compliant. However, it is your responsibility to ensure that appropriate HIPAA-compliant measures are in place with any third party (or third party application, add-on, system or database) before sharing or transmitting PHI.

Comment: this is exactly what I did. It doesn't use imap, it uses the gmail api. Is the gmail api HIPAA compliant? I can't be sure it is.

Comment: The process until that point since the API is cover by HIPAA, it's HIPAA compliance, once it's outside of Workspace it depends on how you mange the data.

Comment: oauth just handles auth, not transmission...is the cypher up to snuff?

Comment: OAuth is just the authorization to access the data, the information it's still encrypted. You can read more information about it in this guide that I found about Google Workspace HIPAA implementation [here](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/gsuite_cloud_identity_hipaa_implementation_guide.pdf#page=26&zoom=100,96,716), under `Use of third party applications, systems, or databases`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. It turns out application passwords are available, just not clearly visible where to find them.